# How to quicksort list of lists in prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog, quicksort, nested-lists

I'm trying to implement quicksort in Prolog with list of lists, using the 4th element as key, but it is not working what i did.

Example:

`?- qsort( [ [ a,b,c,5 ], [ d,e,f,10 ], [ g,h,i,5 ], [ j,k,l,1 ], [ m,n,o,25 ] ], Sort ).`

Expected result:

`[ [ j,k,l,1 ], [ a,b,c,5 ], [ g,h,i,5 ], [ d,e,f,10 ], [ m,n,o,25 ] ]`

What I got as answer (i need to fix the parentheses):

`Sort = [j, k, l, 1, [g, h, i, 5], [a, b, c, 5], [d, e, f, 10], m, n, o, 25]`

This is the closest approach for now:

```
last([Y],Y).
last([_|Xs],Y) :- last(Xs,Y).

qsort([],[]):- !.
qsort([X], [X]).
qsort([Head|Tail],Sorted):-
  last(Head,Pivot),
  separation(Pivot,Tail,Lesser,Greater),
  qsort(Lesser,LesserSorted),
  qsort(Greater,GreaterSorted),
  append(LesserSorted,[Head|GreaterSorted],Sorted).

separation(_,[],[],[]).
separation(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Lesser],Greater):-
  last(X,R), R =< Pivot, 
  separation(Pivot,T,Lesser,Greater).
separation(Pivot,[X|T],Lesser,[X|Greater]):-
  last(X,R), R > Pivot, 
  separation(Pivot,T,Lesser,Greater).
```

Comment: Use `@=<` instead of `=<`, and `@>` instead of `>`: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(@%3C)/2

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i use what you said but the program has crashed, and with a message "the arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"

Comment: but you did not first select a `Pivot`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this is exactly what i did...separation(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Lesser],Greater):- [_,_,_,C],C @=< Pivot,separation(Pivot,T,Lesser,Greater).
separation(Pivot,[X|T],Lesser,[X|Greater]):- [_,_,_,C],C @> Pivot,separation(Pivot,T,Lesser,Greater).

Comment: Why calling last/2 from separation/4 ? You should compare X with Pivot...

Comment: "it is not working" how's that? include specific details please. ---- to include code in your comments, enclose it between double-backticks like this: `\`\`code\`\``.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what *"pivot"* means. You meant to sort the lists using their 4th element as the *key* for  comparisons. "Pivot" is the element you choose to serve as the divider, for partitioning. Your elements happen to be 4-field tuples (encoded as lists, coincidentally). So you choose first element in the list as the pivot, and use 4th fields of your elements to compare them with the pivot element's 4th field. *Pivot* and *key* are separate concepts.

Specifically, this

```erlang
qsort([Head|Tail],Sorted):-
  last(Head,Pivot),
   %% this:         vvvv
  separation(Pivot,[Head|Tail],Lesser,Greater),
```

must be this

```erlang
  separation(Pivot, Tail, Lesser, Greater),
   %%               ^^^^
  qsort(Lesser,LesserSorted),
  qsort(Greater,GreaterSorted),
```

because here

```erlang
  append(LesserSorted,[Head|GreaterSorted],Sorted).
   %%                  ^^^^
```

you assume it was removed from the list before the partitioning (as it indeed should be).